# Global variable. I'm doing something wrong I just don't know what

Tags: python-2.7, global

I have a class and I'm trying to get the text out of it. Right now all of this is written in one file. I haven't moved anything to another file.

Here is my code with comments.

```
prompt = '> ' #This was here for my game. I just used it as a test for def thing()

def thing():
    global prompt #global works like it should here.
    paint = prompt #changed so I can print it but I'm sure I could have just skipped this.
    return paint #I could have probably put prompt here without the previous line just fine.

print thing() #test looks good.

text = "" # I added this to see if I could figure out what's going on. 
# I don't get an error when this is here but it's not what I'm looking to do.

class grid_object:
    x = 1 # x of grid
    y = 1 # y of grid
    player_here = '0' #0 = the player was never here. - = the player was here. X = the player is here.
    text = " " # I change this with another function below. This is what I'm trying to access.
    been_here_text = " " # I change this with another function below. 
    been_here_before_bool = False #This gets toggled elsewhere.

    def text_to_type(self):
        global text #So this will point to the text up top but what I want is the text in the class.
        #How do I get the text I want? That is my question to you guys. 
        to_print = text #Probably don't need this like the test above. 
        return to_print
```

How do I get the `text` that I want to access.

Comment: You can use `grid_object.text` or `self.text` to access it. It's not a global variable, it's a class attribute. Also, you probably don't need `global prompt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really utilizing your `class` correctly. Do this instead:

```
class grid_object(object): # inherit from object for new-style classes
    def __init__(self): # when you instantiate the class, this function runs
        self.x, self.y = 1, 1
        self.player_here = '0'
        self.text = " "
        self.been_here_text = " "
        self.been_here_before_bool = False
    def text_to_type(self):
        return self.text
        # this whole function is silly, just reference
        # self.text any time you would do grid_object().text_to_type()
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> obj = grid_object()
>>> obj.text
" "
>>> obj.x
1
>>> obj.y
1
>>> obj.been_here_before_bool
False
```

The trick here is that you're modifying an OBJECT not the class itself. That's why everything has `self.` in front of it in your class definition. You're not talking about the class anymore, you're talking about something belonging to the instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly. I have a list of grid_objects() in a grid.    

' grid[35].self.text = "This is the entrance to the cave. Find the treasure if you dare." '

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Also sorry for the spam. I'm trying to get my code to show as code but, like always, I'm doing something wrong. :)

Comment: @Mike let's talk about it [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57439/primer-on-python-classes)